# Derived class's new constructor not building: "overloaded member function not found"

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, constructor, sfml

I have 2 classes that are derived and I want them to have their own constructors, not the base classes'. Here are the header and .cpp with the other member functions stripped.

Header:

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class TextWrap : public sf::Text
{
public:
    TextWrap() {}
};

class CircleWrap : public sf::CircleShape
{
public:
    CircleWrap() {}
};
```

Here is the .cpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "wrappers.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

TextWrap::TextWrap(sf::Font font)
{
    setFont(font);
    setCharacterSize(30);
    setStyle(sf::Text::Bold);
    setColor(sf::Color::White);
}

CircleWrap::CircleWrap(void)
{
    setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    setRadius(25);
    setPointCount(100);
}
```

When this is built I get the following error in Visual C++ 2010:

```
1>c:\users\joe\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mouseavoider\mouseavoider\wrappers.cpp(14): error C2511: 'TextWrap::TextWrap(sf::Font)' : overloaded member function not found in 'TextWrap'
1>          c:\users\joe\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mouseavoider\mouseavoider\wrappers.h(5) : see declaration of 'TextWrap'
1>c:\users\joe\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mouseavoider\mouseavoider\wrappers.cpp(38): error C2084: function 'CircleWrap::CircleWrap(void)' already has a body
1>          c:\users\joe\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\mouseavoider\mouseavoider\wrappers.h(16) : see previous definition of '{ctor}'
```

I have a feeling that my syntax is wrong with making the constructor... But I don't know why. I've looked through tutorials and examples online and I don't know why this doesn't work.

EDIT: It's been fixed! I had mixed up the declarations and definitions and needed to fix my declarations of the variables themselves.

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward. You already have a definition in your class definition, yet you redefine it later on. As well as that, your definition's parameter list differs from its prototype. You don't get an error for `CircleWrap` because it's void.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in the first constructor is that you're declaring a default constructor, instead of a constructor with an `sf::Font` as argument.

In the second constructor, you are putting `{}`, meaning that you're defining the constructor with no content.
If you want to define the body of the constructor later you must put a `;` at the end.

It should be:

```
class TextWrap : public sf::Text
{
public:
    TextWrap(sf::Font font);
};

class CircleWrap : public sf::CircleShape
{
public:
    CircleWrap();
};
```

Comment: EDIT:This almost has it solved! You were right, I got mixed up and put the `{}` after the declarations. I've made the changes you said and now I'm getting `'TextWrap' : no appropriate default constructor available`.

Comment: In that case you should declare another constructor, like: `TextWrap(){}` or `TextWrap();` if you want to implement it in a .cpp file

Answer (score 1):

You have overloaded the default constructor, but appear to be accessing a non default version.

Answer (score 0):

The header file should contain *declarations* instead of *definitions*. `TextWrap() {}` is defining a constructor that takes no arguments and has an empty body - the braces are the empty body.  Your class declaration should look more like the following:

```
class TextWrap : public sf::Text {
public:
    TextWrap(sf:Font font);
}
```

The parameters in the declaration/prototype have to match those in the definition (e.g., source file) and the declaration should not include the empty body.

Comment: Thank you! xorguy and you have fixed that issue... Now I'm getting `'TextWrap' : no appropriate default constructor available`, though... Any ideas? I thought that I wasn't supposed to be using the default constructor.

Comment: Are you declaring a statically allocated `TextWrap` instance (e.g., `TextWrap foo;` instead of `TextWrap foo(font)` or `TextWrap *foo;`) or creating a STL container of `TextWrap` instances (e.g., `std::vector<TextWrap>`) that requires a default constructor?  Add the error messages to your question.